# Why do most MRI machines and fusion reactors use helium-cooled superconducting magnets instead of cheaper, higher-temperature nitrogen-cooled ones?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, fusion

I am always hearing about the high (and increasing) costs of helium, as well as the difficulty of handling it....

Are there no high(ish) temperature superconductors that can create a strong enough magnetic field?

Or are they all 'Type-II' superconductors in which 'holes' (vortices) appear in the supermagnets (weak Meissner Effect) and destabilize the machines?

P.S.:  If I may, may I add a second question?  Why is it so hard to contain and recycle the helium in helium-cooled devices anyway?

Answer (score 3):

For MRI the main issue is that high temperature superconductors tend to be rather brittle and not very ductile. So it is difficult to machine them into the necessary shape for the magnet.

Modern magnets typically have a “zero boil off” design. So they just recycle the helium internally. So you need the helium to fill the magnet, but you do not need to continuously re-supply helium during normal operation

Answer (score 1):

So high-temperature superconductor coils/tapes are really expensive, but they do not let us get rid of liquid helium anyway, as

> the HTS materials are suitable for high field applications only at
> operating temperature  <25 K, because the critical current density at
> high field dramatically drops above 25 K.

(Pierluigi Bruzzone et al 2018 Nucl. Fusion 58 103001
DOI 10.1088/1741-4326/aad835)

Another problem with HTS is that

> their Normal Zone Propagation Velocity (NZPV) is several orders of
> magnitude slower than for NbTi. This parameter measures how quickly
> the magnet can spread its stored energy during a quench event. If the
> magnet is not sufficiently fast, hot spots are more prone to occur
> before the traditional quench protection methods can detect them

(https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.08918)